# Why JRE 8 32 bit and 64 bit offline installation files for WIndows have so big difference in size?

Tags: java

According to the [download page](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) JRE8 32 bit has 28.3 MB in size and JRE8 64 bit has 88.3 MB.
Why the difference is so huge?
For comparison, [JRE7](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual_java7.jsp): 28 MB and 29.5 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually download and install both, the 64-bit version is just a bit more than 10% bigger when uncompressed. The first plausible explanation, then, would be that the 64-bit binaries don't compress as well. Why that might be the case I cannot say.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. 7-zip can compress them (JRE8-25 installation files) to 28.3 MB and 29.5 MB respectively.